# Debug images (Mat) with OpenCvSharp

Tags: c#, opencv, debugging, mat, image-viewer

I am learning how to use an OpenCv wrapper for C# (OpenCvSharp). I am pretty new at it, but I did try OpenCv in C++. In C++ we can use Image Viewer to debug images. I would like to do the same for the OpenCvSharp wrapper.

The only thing I have found is a link to https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp/wiki/Debugger-Visualizer

So far if I click on the magnifying lens I can see the image, but I would love to have information as detailed as the Image viewer in C++. There I can check pixels' values and the image in a docked window which is much more convenient for debugging.

Would anyone know how to obtain some OpenCvSharp wrapper?

Thanks for your time.